# Django project for events of the day, grouped by keywords in common

Tags: python, graph, django, data-visualization, natural-language-processing

I have made a website where people write about their day and see it analyzed. In particular, the website takes event titles and groups them together if they have any common words (after stemming the event titles). It also finds miscellaneous features that I feel would be important for machine learning later. The python file that is most important is `views.py`. The class that is most important is `EventAnalysis`, and its most important methods are `string_clean` and `feature_engineering`. I've included `models.py` for one to make sense of `views.py`. For more information (and for running the complete project), [here is the GitHub link](https://github.com/boworkgo/Past-patterns).

views.py

```
import random
import re
import sqlite3
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import datetime
from functools import reduce

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from django import forms
from django.forms import Textarea
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.urls import reverse, reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic

import pandas as pd
from chartjs.views.lines import BaseLineChartView
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
from pandas.io import sql

from .models import Event


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = "posts/index.html"
    context_object_name = "latest_posts"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Event.objects.all()[:10]


class HistoryView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Event
    template_name = "posts/history.html"
    context_object_name = "post"


class CreateView(generic.edit.CreateView):
    model = Event
    fields = ["title", "text"]
    exclude = ["pub_date"]
    widgets = {"text": Textarea(attrs={"cols": 100, "rows": 15})}
    template_name = "posts/create.html"

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("posts:index")


class Graph:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.number_edges = n
        self.visited = [False] * n
        self.adj = defaultdict(list)
        self.connections = []

    def add_edge(self, n1, n2):
        self.adj[n1].append(n2)
        self.adj[n2].append(n1)

    def dfs(self):
        for i in range(self.number_edges):
            if not self.visited[i]:
                self.connections.append([])
                self.traverse_adj(i)

    def traverse_adj(self, i):
        self.connections[len(self.connections) - 1].append(i)
        self.visited[i] = True
        for j in self.adj[i]:
            if not self.visited[j]:
                self.traverse_adj(j)


class EventAnalysis:
    def __init__(self):
        conn = sqlite3.connect("db.sqlite3")
        self.data = sql.read_sql("SELECT * FROM posts_event;", con=conn)
        conn.close()
        self.clean_data()
        self.feature_engineering()

    def string_clean(self, s):
        s = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z ]+", "", s).lower()
        s = re.sub(" +", " ", s).strip().split(" ")
        stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english"))
        s = [w for w in s if not w in stop_words]
        ps = PorterStemmer()
        s = list(set([ps.stem(w) for w in s]))
        return s

    def clean_data(self):
        self.data["cleansed_title"] = self.data["title"].map(self.string_clean)
        self.data["cleansed_text"] = self.data["text"].map(self.string_clean)

    def calculate_hours(self, time1, time2):
        def difference(idx1, idx2):
            return int(time2[idx1:idx2]) - int(time1[idx1:idx2])

        year = difference(0, 4)
        month = difference(5, 7)
        day = difference(8, 10)
        hour = difference(11, 13)
        minute = difference(14, 16)
        return year * 365 * 24 + month * 30 * 24 + day * 24 + hour + minute / 60

    def feature_engineering(self):
        time_spent, day_id = [1], []
        anchor_day, day_i = self.data["pub_date"][0][:10], 1
        for i in range(self.data.shape[0]):
            if i != 0:
                time_spent.append(
                    self.calculate_hours(
                        self.data["pub_date"][i - 1], self.data["pub_date"][i]
                    )
                )
            if self.data["pub_date"][i][:10] != anchor_day:
                day_i += 1
                anchor_day = self.data["pub_date"][i][:10]
            day_id.append(day_i)
        self.last_day_id = day_i
        self.data["time_spent"] = time_spent
        self.data["day_id"] = day_id
        self.data["is_important"] = self.data["title"].map(lambda x: x != "*")

        connected_components = Graph(len(self.data["id"]))
        added_edges = set()
        for i, title in enumerate(self.data["cleansed_title"]):
            for j, other in enumerate(self.data["cleansed_title"]):
                if (
                    i != j
                    and set(title) & set(other)
                    and frozenset({i, j}) not in added_edges
                ):
                    connected_components.add_edge(i, j)
                    added_edges.add(frozenset({i, j}))
        connected_components.dfs()
        group_number = 1
        id_group = dict()
        for group in connected_components.connections:
            for n in group:
                id_group[n] = group_number
            group_number += 1
        self.last_group_number = group_number
        self.data["group_id"] = [id_group[i] for i in range(self.data.shape[0])]
        self.data["pub_date_datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(
            self.data["pub_date"], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", errors="coerce"
        )
        time = pd.DataFrame(self.data[["pub_date_datetime", "time_spent"]])
        time = time.set_index(["pub_date_datetime"])
        time = time.resample("D").mean()
        self.time_df = time

    def past_day_pie(self):
        past_day = self.data[self.data.day_id == self.last_day_id]
        total = sum(past_day["time_spent"])
        percentages = past_day["time_spent"].map(lambda x: x / total)
        return list(percentages), list(past_day["title"])

    def grouping_pie(self):
        group_hours, group_words = [], []
        for i in range(1, self.last_group_number):
            group = self.data[self.data.group_id == i]
            group_hours.append(sum(group["time_spent"]))
            words = reduce(lambda a, b: set(a) | set(b), group["cleansed_title"], [])
            group_words.append(
                "\n".join(
                    [
                        w
                        for w in set(
                            random.sample(words, 4 if 4 <= len(words) else len(words))
                        )
                    ]
                )
            )
        return group_hours, group_words

    def time_plot(self):
        return (list(self.time_df["time_spent"]), self.time_df.index.tolist())


def analytics(request):
    if len(Event.objects.all()) > 0:
        print(e.data)
    return render(
        request, "posts/analytics.html", context={"events": Event.objects.all()}
    )


class DeleteView(generic.DeleteView):
    model = Event

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("posts:index")


class ChartJSONView(BaseLineChartView):
    def __init__(self, method):
        self.stats, self.labels = method

    def get_labels(self):
        return self.labels

    def get_data(self):
        return [self.stats]

    def get_context_data(self):
        return {"labels": self.get_labels(), "datasets": self.get_datasets()}


e = EventAnalysis()


class GroupingPieChartJSONView(ChartJSONView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(e.grouping_pie())


class PastDayPieChartJSONView(ChartJSONView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(e.past_day_pie())


class AverageHoursJSONView(ChartJSONView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(e.time_plot())
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    text = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-pub_date"]

    def was_important(self):
        return self.title != "*"
```